# Point operator C++

Tags: c++, image-processing, cimg

I have the following piece of code for image processing, using the library CImg.

```
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
  for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) { 
      width = in.
      float weight = strength*x*(xmax-x)*y*(ymax-y)/(xmax*xmax)/(ymax*ymax);
      int new_x  = (int) ((1-weight)*x + weight*      y * xmax/ymax);
      int new_y  = (int) ((1-weight)*y + weight*(xmax-x)* ymax/xmax);
      out(x,y) = in(new_x,new_y);
  }
```

What does it mean the following line at the start of the cycle?

```
  width = in.
```

'width' and 'in' are respectively an int and a CImg object declared before.

Thank you.

Comment: That line means that the code has a syntax error.

Comment: did you just cut away `dimx();` ?

Comment: @Niall there is no line like yours in the other part of the code.

Comment: @interjay the code is running perfectly.

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit The declaration of width is this: const int width = in.dimx();   but in the cycle the line is just that

Comment: Is that `.` correct?

Comment: @charles No, it won't compile. You're probably not running what you think you are. Either you're compiling another file or you didn't save the changes in the editor.

Comment: @charles, be honest, you copied http://www.vision.ee.ethz.ch/~cvcourse/exercises/ex_0_materials/warp.cc and made a copy/paste mistake that doesn't compile

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That line is a syntax error, and will not pass compilation. It most likely was accidentally pasted there.

Googling for the code gives [this](http://www.vision.ee.ethz.ch/~cvcourse/exercises/ex_0_materials/warp.cc), which contains the same code without that line:

```
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
  for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
    float weight = strength*x*(xmax-x)*y*(ymax-y)/(xmax*xmax)/(ymax*ymax);
    int new_x  = (int) ((1-weight)*x + weight*      y * xmax/ymax);
    int new_y  = (int) ((1-weight)*y + weight*(xmax-x)* ymax/xmax);
    out(x,y) = in(new_x,new_y);
  }
```

Another part of the code contains the line `const int width = in.dimx();`, which is probably the source of the accidental copy/paste.

Comment: An answer doesn't always have to be complex to get upvotes. +1 from me ;)